# Why can I use a string literal as a class in php7?

Tags: php, php-7

Consider the following code:

```
class foo {
    static $bar = 'baz';
}
var_dump('foo'::$bar);
```

---

It throws an error in PHP5 (as expected):

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in **[...][...]** on line **4**

---

But it works without an issue in PHP7 and outputs:

```
string(3) "baz"
```

---

Is that intentional or a bug?

Comment: You can add this phrase at the end of your sentence: `Or am I missing some thing` ;-)

Comment: Which version of PHP5 was this supposed to work in?

Comment: It does not work in PHP 5.5+ I've just tested it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: @mario the last available one 5.6.20

Comment: @mortezaT most likely you're right :) but I can't find anything concerning that change

Comment: @rap-2-h yes, and that reasonable. At least to me.

Comment: It looks like they've made variable classes more general, you can put any expression that evaluates to a class name before `::`.

Comment: This is due to https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax. Dereferencable scalars are now allowed as the left hand side of all dereferencing operations, rather than being limited to array dereferencing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's because they rewrote stuff regarding evaluation.

like the following is not possible in PHP5 but in PHP 7:

```
echo (new X)->toString();
```

Same would go for

```
echo ('X')::$bar
```

See [Changes to the handling of indirect variables, properties, and methods](http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect)

This is mainly about the left-to-right evaluation but it also affects the evaluation in general.

More information can be found on [PHP RFC: Uniform Variable Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) (Status: implemented) - Thanks to [Nikic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468161/why-can-i-use-a-string-literal-as-a-class-in-php7/38468719#comment64343727_38468161):

> This RFC proposes the introduction of an internally consistent and
>   complete variable syntax. To achieve this goal the semantics of some
>   rarely used variable-variable constructions need to be changed.

Answer (score 5):

The general direction that PHP has been moving for years has been to be more flexible and general in use of variable variables, variable functions, and variable classes. In PHP5, when you want to use a variable class, you have to put the class name in a variable:

```
$class = 'foo';
echo $class::$foo;
```

It looks like PHP7 has made this more general, allowing any expression there, rather than requiring a variable. For instance, you can write:

```
$c1 = 'f';
$c2 = 'oo';
echo ($c1 . $c2)::$foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find anything in the docs at the moment but I would suspect that this could be expected behavior.

Consider the following in PHP 5 with no errors:

```
function hello()
{
    echo "hi";
}
$hi = 'hello';
$hi();
```

`$hi` is a string so it seems like they've simply decided to add support for ad-hoc strings.

It kind of makes sense that `'hello'();` is valid in PHP7

---

**Update**

You can find a small reference to PHP 7.0.0 at the bottom of their examples at http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: I see inconsistency here. Assuming that php7 support scalar types like string, that's quite strange that you can invoke function or something else that way.

Comment: @seclu Hmm, I'll have to look into that but I think the other two answers might provide the more technical explanation that you are looking for. I +1'd them.